# The inverse is a root of the reciprocal (reverse) polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and let $a \neq 0$ be a zero of the polynomial $a_0 + a_1x + . . . +a_nx^n$ in $F[x]$.

I want to show that $\frac{1}{a}$ is a zero of the polynomial $a_n + a_{n-1}x + . . . + a_0x^n$

How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: try $y=\frac 1x$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ The second reversed (aka [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial)) polynomial is simply $\ \hat f(x)= x^n f(1/x),\,\ n = \deg f.\,$ Now verify that $\hat f(1/a) = 0\,$ since $\,f(a) = 0.$

Comment: how does this help me?

Comment: @ter Try evaluating the above at $\,x = 1/a,\,$ using $\,f(a)=0.$

Comment: It just seems like the problem wants me to use the originally polynomial to derive that the reversed one has 1/a as a root.

Comment: @ter That's precisely what you'll be doing if you follow my hint, since the proof that $\,\hat f(1/a) = 0\,$ uses $\,f(a) = 0.$