# If $a/b$ is a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients, show that $a$ divides the constant term and $b$ divides the leading coefficient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> Let $p(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \cdots + c_d x^d$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients $c_0, \ldots, c_d \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $c_d \neq 0$, so $p(x)$ has degree $d$. Let $a/b$ be a rational root of $p(x)$ written in lowest terms. How do I see that $a \mid c_0$ and $b \mid c_d$?

Comment: Is this not precisely the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)?

Comment: it is obvious when you write $p(x) = (x- \frac{a}{b}) \sum_{k=0}^{d-1} u_k x^k $

Comment: Do you know anything about polynomial long division? If you do, I will try to write something nice up for you.

Comment: @user1952009 That's assuming you know Gauss's Lemma or equivalent results, e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/8721/242)

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$c_0 + c_1\frac{a}{b}+ \cdots c_d(\frac{a}{b})^d  = 0$$ is true. Multiplying both sides by $b^d$, we get $$c_0b^d + c_1 a b^{d-1}+ \cdots c_da^d  = 0.$$ Right side is divisible by $a$ and $b$ so left side is also divisible by $a$ and $b$. I believe you can finish it from here!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\frac ab$ is a root of $P(x)$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1.$ i.e. $\frac ab$ is in lowest terms.

$P(\frac ab) = c_0 + c_1 \frac ab+c_2 \frac {a^2}{b^2} \cdots + c_d\frac {a^d}{b^d} = 0\\
c_1 \frac ab+c_2 \frac {a^2}{b^2} \cdots + c_d\frac {a^d}{b^d} = -c_0$

Every term on the left side of the equals sign is divisble by $a.$  Therefore $c_0$ is divisible by $a.$

Multiply trough by $b^d$ and rearrange the terms.

$c_d a^d = - c_0 b^d - c_1 a b^{d-1}  \dots -c^{d-1} a^{d-1}b$

And similarly, every term on the right is divisible by $b,$ therefore $c_d$ is divisible by $b.$

Answer (score 0):

First note you can assume $a$ and $b$ are coprime ($gcd(a,b)$=1).
By substitution $x=\frac{a}{b}$ you get

$c_0+c_1\frac{a}{b}+\dots+c_d\frac{a^d}{b^d}=0$

Then multiply by $b^d$

$c_0b^d+c_1ab^{d-1}+\dots+c_da^d=0$

Now you see that $a$ divides the RHS, so it must divide LHS. But since it divides every summand except possibly $c_0b^d$, it must also divide this one. But $\gcd(a,b^n)=1$, so it must be $a\,|\,c_0$.
By the same reasoning (swap $a$ and $b$, $c_0$ and $c_d$) you get $b\,|\,c_d$.

EDIT: I'm sorry for repeating the above posts, they weren't there when I started replying. I believed the website would have informed me before posting if other answer appeared while I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *modular* proof: $\,\bmod a\!:\ b^{-1}$ exists by $\,(a,b)=1,\,$ so  $\,a/b\equiv ab^{-1}\equiv 0,\,$ so

$$\ {\rm mod}\ a\!:\,\ 0 \equiv p(a/b) \equiv p(0)\ \Rightarrow\, a\mid p(0) = c_0$$

The [reversed poly](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692196/242) $\ \bar p(x) = x^d p(1/x)\ $ has root $\, b/a,\,$ hence $\ b\mid \bar p(0) = c_d\,$ by above.

**Remark** $\ $ The is usually called the [Rational Root Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) The above proof presumes that you know that modular arithmetic (congruences) can be extended to fractions with denominators coprime to the modulus (see the [discussion here),](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) a property which is greatly clarified when one studies ring theory (the universal properties of fraction rings or localizations).

Comment: Not if $\,a=0\,$ then $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\, b=1\,$ so $\,b\mid c_d,\,$ so we meed only consider the case $\,a\neq 0$ in the reversed case with root $\,b/a.\ $