# Proving that simple polynomials with an integer solution can always be solved with modular arithmetic.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Using this equation as an example $$5 x^2 + 7 x - 66 = 0$$
It has x=3 as a solution (also -4.4 but we'll ignore that). 
 Apparently we can solve this using modular arithmetic for any modulus. E.g. for modulus=4 we have
$$1 \cdot x^2 + 3 x - 2 \equiv 0$$
which also yields x=3 (because $x^2$ = 9 which is congruent to 1, ditto for 3x).

**I'd like to prove that this always works** using ordinary algebra, but I'm not sure how. Sticking with mod 4, I tried rewriting the first equation as  $$(4+1) x^2 + (4+3) x - (64+2) = 0$$
and then rearrange
$$ \left[ 4 x^2 + 4 x - 64 \right] + \left[ x^2 +3 x -2 \right]  = 0$$
It seems that mod 4 would allow me to remove the left bracket, but that doesn't make sense since it doesn't equal zero for x=3 (also x=3 is not a solution of the right bracket). So I'm at an impasse, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that your question is "If $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $n$ is an integer such that $p(n)=0$, then is $p(n)\equiv 0\pmod m$ for any modulus $m$?" If so, the answer is yes and it follows directly from the definition of congruence (and has nothing to do with polynomials). Note that it doesn't go the other way: your first congruence has $z=-1$ as a solution, but $x=-1$ is not a solution to the original equation.

Comment: It is true that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coef's then any root of $f$ in $\Bbb Z$ persists as a root in $\Bbb Z_n$, by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the first linked dupe.

Comment: More generally roots persist mod all divisors of the modulus (above is the special case of modulus $ = 0,\,$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3951429/242)), e.g. a root $\!\bmod 10\,$ remains a root $\!\bmod 2\,$ so if there are no roots $\!\bmod 2\,$ then there are no roots $\!\bmod 10,\,$ a special *parity* case of the [modular root test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1280619/242). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4468139/242) for more on solving modular quadratics.

Comment: Further the above generalizes to any rational root that has denominator coprime to the modulus, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1857434/242) and its links.

Comment: Thanks for the Polynomial Congruence Rule, that's what I needed.